# How to protect Angular code with OAuth2 with an external IdentityServer

Tags: angular, openid-connect

Scenario:
Simple Hello World Angular app that get's the message Hello World from an API.

We don't want to expose the Angular app's code, so we need an access token to be validated before releasing the code, and we want the same access token to be able to access the API.

In my head I think that this shouldn't be handled by the application layer.  It should be handled by the webserver, but it seems that Angular OIDC facilities never took this into consideration.

Right now I have a hand-crafted middleware on the server hosting the SPA that intercepts all calls (of which there is only ever one: the call to get the Angular app), and 302s to the IdentityServer before anything can load.  If there is a token it sets a header, and in the app we manually grab the token and use it for API calls.

There's a number of things I haven't figured out with this approach.  Like what happens if the token expires?  I should be using oidc-client; right?  But I won't be using it to get the token because the token will already exist, and I'll want to use that token.

I didn't come to this conclusion myself; either.  NGINX does have plugins that handle OAuth2 so that code can't be accessed.  But what I do after I have the application is a little confusing to me.

Comment: Not answering your question, but you can't protect the code - it runs and is interpreted on the client - users will be able to inspect it. You're essentially asking how to protect your entire site with a password request pre-load that's it. If this is a strategy to keep a trade secret, it won't work - if you want your code to be secure, do server side processing.

Comment: @Matt, I don't care if employees have access to the app as much as I care about random people coming across the app and rooting around for endpoints and launching attacks.  I mean if an employee has access, they are much more likely to be able to do damage anyways.  Like I wouldn't leave my book of important corporate secrets on the subway, but new employees are going to have to see some of those secrets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you have your Identity Server setup, you may be able to use the same application config in the IdentityServer for the JavaScript client to access the API to also configure a module for the web server to require a token before providing the code.  The server will bounce back to ask for login credentials twice, but on the second time, for the JavaScript client, the user will already have a token for that application with the IdentityServer and the login will occur without the user's knowledge.